# Suddenly a server refuses to 'apt update' because an 'Unknown error executing apt-key'

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

**The problem**

*UPDATE: Currently investigating with strace. <s>It seems problem is a HTTP 400 error when accessing the repository</s>*

*UPDATE2: More weird errors in the server (a .so lib file corrupted, database engine displaying 'Unknown error') so it seems this problem is due to a hardware error.*

```
Unknown error executing apt-key
```

For example, an fragment of a `apt update` execution:

```
[...]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [56,6 kB] 
[...]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
[...]
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
[...]
```

This was working perfectly since long ago and started to happen overnight. Nothing special was done to the server.

I have other servers with almost the same configuration and they are working ok.

I see no relevant entries in apt and system logs.

**What I've tried**

There are some posts that say I've to delete `/var/lib/apt`, check the trusted keys and similar approaches. None worked.

I've checked the output of `apt-key list`: the list is almost the same as another server that works ok, the other server just has one more key for the Jenkins repository.

The output is something like this:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-security-automatic.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [SC] [expires: 2029-01-15]
      AC53 0D52 0F2F 3269 F5E9  8313 A484 4904 4AAD 5C5D
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [S] [expires: 2029-01-15]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-stable.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-02-13 [SC] [expires: 2029-02-11]
      A428 5295 FC7B 1A81 6000  62A9 605C 66F0 0D6C 9793
uid           [ unknown] Debian Stable Release Key (11/bullseye) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [SC] [expires: 2027-04-12]
      80D1 5823 B7FD 1561 F9F7  BCDD DC30 D7C2 3CBB ABEE
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [S] [expires: 2027-04-12]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [SC] [expires: 2027-04-12]
      5E61 B217 265D A980 7A23  C5FF 4DFA B270 CAA9 6DFA
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [S] [expires: 2027-04-12]
```

Because I have other servers with almost the same configuration (same Debian 10 OS, very similar installed packages, etc) I desperately tried copying their `/var/lib/apt` and `/ec/apt` folders to this faulty server: the error persists.

Because I suspect GPG could be wrong, I tried to reinstall it. I downloaded the package from Debian repository and installed using dpkg: same result, issue persists.

**Enabling apt debugging: what is different from a working server**

You can enable apt debugging. In my case I use:

```
apt -o Debug::Acquire::http=false -o Debug::Hashes=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth=true -o Debug::sourceList=true  update
```

This is interesting. I've commented all sources but `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free`. The faulty server yields:

```
# apt -o Debug::Acquire::http=false -o Debug::Hashes=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth=true -o Debug::sourceList=true  update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
        - SHA512:c65abc258e9ecc7e506133502add58d9c451bc11c3dd9bf7f23a0d58fb0f7747cc75bee22e58dece5af63f6a1cc7dd7c150a383fbd79ce23655c7aca6c32b78c
        - SHA256:45420bba913bb4d35b98319d893d9db2bc0c4034a12c65f07118dd36ee4cea86
        - SHA1:dcbc9207da6730f5a268f7c8f452ad62f0fd9705
        - MD5Sum:2f497e0885083bf377d7f5cafe9b1762
        - Checksum-FileSize:121570
ExpectedHash:

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

However, the working servers outputs:

```
# apt -o Debug::Acquire::http=false -o Debug::Hashes=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth=true -o Debug::sourceList=true  update
0% [Working]201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
ExpectedHash:

Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
0% [Working]201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
ExpectedHash:

Signature verification succeeded: /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease
Got Codename: buster
Got Suite: oldstable
Expecting Dist: buster
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

As you can see, the faulty server seems to receive some hashes and has no expected hash while the working sever has no hashes at all?

**What about other sources?** If I try with `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free`, the fault servers outputs:

```
# apt -o Debug::Acquire::http=false -o Debug::Hashes=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth=true -o Debug::sourceList=true  update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [56,6 kB]
0% [1 InRelease 56,6 kB/56,6 kB 100%]201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
        - SHA512:3542a4de41bdffba0631f27efdf2dd69602b77b1dd7362285527d3e96d22daaae1165979fc83a740049e2c54de455f798c07f0120baeafd316dd2e9efd68faab
        - SHA256:65d8f69e329505a4abdc3968778e36adae20b8542eed9745c60c47bc90ea4c05
        - SHA1:e901931cf25b06819fe1a653b39621b5e42a0109
        - MD5Sum:db7403e0f919a66b1e05ed537962d333
        - Checksum-FileSize:56621
ExpectedHash:

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

More or less the same error than before. It includes several keys in ReceivedHash but empty value in ExpectedHash.

What about the working server? It outputs:

```
# apt -o Debug::Acquire::http=false -o Debug::Hashes=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Auth=true -o Debug::sourceList=true  update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [56,6 kB]
0% [1 InRelease 16,4 kB/56,6 kB 29%]201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
        - SHA512:3542a4de41bdffba0631f27efdf2dd69602b77b1dd7362285527d3e96d22daaae1165979fc83a740049e2c54de455f798c07f0120baeafd316dd2e9efd68faab
        - SHA256:65d8f69e329505a4abdc3968778e36adae20b8542eed9745c60c47bc90ea4c05
        - SHA1:e901931cf25b06819fe1a653b39621b5e42a0109
        - MD5Sum:db7403e0f919a66b1e05ed537962d333
        - Checksum-FileSize:56621
ExpectedHash:

0% [Working]201 URI Done: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease
ReceivedHash:
ExpectedHash:

Signature verification succeeded: /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster-updates_InRelease
```

....and lot of other lines about other files it downloads, but I guess they are not interesting for this issue.

In this case, the working server also receives hashes in ReceivedHash and empty value in ExpectedHash.

**Error 400 accessing repository**

Ok, let's dig more into this. Let's use `strace`. This is the interesting part:

```
lchown("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster-updates_InRelease", 100, 0) = 0
lstat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster-updates_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56621, ...}) = 0
chmod("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster-updates_InRelease", 0600) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])   = 18% [Working]", 18
write(1, "\33[0m", 4)                   = 4
select(11, [5 6], [10], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 1 (out [10], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=499997})
write(10, "601 Configuration\nConfig-Item: A"..., 11121) = 11121
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=499997}) = 1 (in [6], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=364398})
read(6, "400 URI Failure\nMessage: Unknown"..., 64000) = 148
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster-updates_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=56621, ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 7
connect(7, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = 0
sendto(7, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0root\0", 17, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 17
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
```

Specifically, this line:

```
read(6, "400 URI Failure\nMessage: Unknown"..., 64000) = 148
```

It seems there's an error during transfer.

**What to do now?**

How I can dig more into the HTTP error? Can I use apt-key to mimic the request that returns 400? What could I do to fix this (apart form ignoring the GPG sign checks)? Or what other checks can I do to locate the root cause of the issue?

Comment: That sounds quite strange. What does `apt-key list` show?

Comment: Indeed quite strange. Just a bunch of keys. The list is exactly the same as another serve that works ok (well, the other server has one more key for the Jenkins repository). I'm adding a fragment of the list to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a reboot with a rescue disk I used `fsck` to check the EXT4 filesystem: there were hundreds of errors.

Then, I reinstalled every installed packaged to fix any corrupt binary file.

After this, the apt error is gone. It was due to a corrupted file related to some package used by `apt`.

UPDATE
SSD was dying ad finally I had to switch to another server. Backups worked, no data was harmed during this incident.

Comment: Anyway, this server probably needs a reinstall to be sure, but it is good to know the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might be the victim of a repository mirroring error. Or a Web filter (if your site has one) might be blocking the system's access to the Debian repository. `deb.debian.org` is a GeoIP redirector, that attempts to connect you to the Debian repository that is closest to you. The Web filter might not have full knowledge of all the addresses the redirector might send you.

The InRelease file could be downloaded manually with a simple:

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease
```

or

```
curl http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease > InRelease
```

As far as I can see, the resulting file has not changed since 2022-09-10 and should be exactly 121570 bytes in size. This agrees with the fact that Debian 10.12 was released on that day, and that release marked [the transition of Debian 10 to Long-Term Support.](https://www.debian.org/News/2022/20220910)

The resulting file should be a PGP-signed text file, that starts with:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Origin: Debian
Label: Debian
Suite: oldstable
Version: 10.13
Codename: buster
Changelogs: http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog
Date: Sat, 10 Sep 2022 11:30:54 UTC
Acquire-By-Hash: yes
```

If you get something different, it might be a notification page from your local web filter proxy (if your site has one), or perhaps the mirror site you ultimately end up connecting to has had a disk failure and has not yet fully re-mirrored that file, possibly resulting an incomplete file. Your strace indicates the `stat()` system call is returning `st_size=56621`, so you seem to be getting an incomplete or different file.

If the resulting file seems to be a HTML file, rename it as `something.html` and view it with a web browser. If it is a notification from a local Web filter, you may have to contact the administrator of that filter. If it is some other HTML error page, the repository `deb.debian.org` is pointing you at might be suffering a fault of some sort.

If you cannot wait for the repository to get fixed, you could always go to https://www.debian.org/mirror/list and pick one or two mirrors close to you, temporarily configure your `sources.list` to use them instead of `deb.debian.org`, and so attempt to work around the faulty repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it seems the problem is elsewhere. The file is short because it is the updates file. I've compared the downloaded file with what another servers download and it is the same. So it seems apt downloaded the file ok but signing check is failing. Today a .so lib file was corrupted and some unknown error in the database happen. I think the SSD drive is just dying and all those weird errors come from there.

Comment: Ouch. Well, a dying SSD could definitely explain it. I hope your backups are good.

Comment: Backups should be ok (at least they were in my last tests). I'll probably know it in short. Thanks!